# "Бутуз"

Tags: этимология

Толстых здоровых малышей называют "бутузами". Только не понятно, откуда взялось это слово.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По Фасмеру (ссылается на Горяева) бутус или бутуз восходит к областному "бутеть" - толстеть.

Вот думаю, не отсюда ли "бутовать". Хотя вряд ли, конечно.